# Erro código Python

Tags: python

Tenho um MAC e tudo funcionava perfeitamente, resolvi instalar o `anaconda` para ver se me ajudaria em algo e agora não rodo mais meus códigos, recebo a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> File
>   "/Users/claytonpereira/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py",
>   line 1692, in genfromtxt
>
> raise ValueError(errmsg)
>
> ValueError: Some errors were detected !
>
> Line #4 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
>
> Line #5 (got 3 columns instead of 1)
>
> Line #7 (got 3 columns instead of 1)

Alguém poderia me dizer o que posso fazer?

Comment: No mínimo você teria de incluir o código que está quebrando, e do jeito que a pergunta está formatada, parece que você simplesmente repassou uma pergunta de um chat para cá.

Answer (score 1):

É difícil responder sua pergunta sem ver o trecho de código que você está tentando executar e os dados que você está usando.

Mas a mensagem de erro que você está vendo parece ser de uma tentativa de usar a função [numpy.genfromtext](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) com um conteúdo que não tem o número de colunas correto, como nesse exemplo:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.genfromtxt(iter(['1', '1', '1 2', '1 2 3', '1 2 3']), skip_header=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/elias/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1692, in genfromtxt
    raise ValueError(errmsg)
ValueError: Some errors were detected !
    Line #3 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
    Line #4 (got 3 columns instead of 1)
    Line #5 (got 3 columns instead of 1)
```

O esperado seria todas as entradas terem o mesmo número de colunas:

```
>>> numpy.genfromtxt(iter(['1 2 3', '1 2 3', '1 2 3', '1 2 3', '1 2 3']), skip_header=True)
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Se realmente o problema começou depois de instalar o anaconda, muito provavelmente seus scripts passaram a utilizar o Python errado em sua máquina.

Abra uma nova janela do Terminal e digite `which python`. Normalmente, no OS X, isso retornaria `/usr/bin/python`. Se retornar algo diferente, como o caminho para sua instalação do anaconda então você vai precisar achar onde o anaconda foi adicionado ao seu $PATH, provavelmente em `~/.bash_profile` ou `~/.bashrc` e remover a alteração.